# Built-in functions for Homotopy group

Tags: functions, function-construction, algebraic-manipulation, built-in-symbols, topology

Does Mathematica have built-in functions for Homotopy group, for example for computing 
$$\pi_n(S^m)=?$$

or more generally
 $n$-th homotopy group, 
$$\pi_n(X)=?$$
for some $X$.
(I search, but I could not find one yet.)